# Read parent URL from included file

Tags: php, variables, include

OK, so I have searched around for long enough to finally post this one here. Sure enough, it has been asked before a zillion time...

What I have, is one file, which includes another. No magic here. The trouble is, the included file then includes another file, which... includes yet another... Yep, a pain. Actually it's all working quite nicely, except that I now wanted to read the URL of the original file in the last of the included files.

So I thought in the original file, file_1.php I just say

```
$var_foo = dirname(__FILE__);
```

or

```
$var_foo = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
```

and then read that value in the first include, file_2.php, passing it on like

```
$var_foo_2 = $var_foo;
```

then in file_3.php

```
$var_foo_3 = $var_foo_2
```

etc, until I arrive at the final file, file_4.php, where I'd like to know the exact value of the original file's URL. Passing it on the first level works OK, but then it gets lost somewhere along the way. Tried going GLOBAL in file_1 -- to no avail.

Since file_3 and file_4 must both execute to produce data, setting a breakpoint a la echo / exit to spoof the current value (if any) is no option. I can live without that particular value, but I just would like to have it -- for the fun of it... Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: If you have defined `$var_foo` in `file_1`, all (nest-)included file can see and work with this variable (unless it's included in function/etc. scope).

Comment: That is, what I had thought, and since the value arrived in file_2 OK, I had thought it was fine. Well, it wasn't - but - that was due to a typo in file_3, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Your examples use filesystem paths, not "URLs";
I am assuming the filepath of the parent file is what you actually want.*

You don't need to "pass" the variable on each included page.  It will automatically be available to the code on the new page.

(If it is not, you may not be in the right scope: e.g., if you're inside a class or function, you'll need to pass it deliberately or use some other method - `global`, maybe, or even define the filename as a constant instead of a variable.)

**main script**

```
$parent_filename = __FILE__;

// alternatively
// define( 'PARENT_FILENAME',__FILE__ );

include "other-file.php";
```

**other-file.php**

```
include "other-dir/somefile.php";
```

**other-dir/somefile.php**

```
print $parent_filename;

// alternatively
// print PARENT_FILENAME;

/* prints something like:

/path/to/main.php

*/
```

Comment: Correct. I had it solved yesterday morning over the second cuppa. Quick and dirty, setting the variable just ahead of the first include, and then lazily adding it to the query string. Perhaps not the most elegant, but works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, the issue has been solved like so:

set variable before the first include
add variable to query string

Thanks all for the input, appreciated.